# Set font size of table by looking for span which contains table?

Tags: php, regex

I need help with regex pattern which will replace/get font size of first "span" before each table and use that span font-size in table style definition but span needs to be without close tag, not yet closed span tag.

from:

```
<span style="font-size:10px;">
<table>...</table>
</span>
```

to:

```
<span style="font-size:10px;">
<table style="font-size:10px;">...</table>
</span>
```

It needs to go all over and for each "table" that is inside some span with font size do same thing.

Comment: [Do not use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/717214)

Comment: What to use if not regex?

Comment: Look at the linked post - HTML parser is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `regex` to parse `html`, use an `html` parser, something like [PHP: DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), i.e.:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<span style="font-size:10px;">
<table>...</table>
</span>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument(); # create DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($html); # Load $html into DOMDocument

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $item) { # find all table elements in html

    $parent = $item->parentNode; # get parent node (<span>)
    $parent_style = $parent->getAttribute('style'); # get style attribute for parent node
    $item->setAttribute('style', $parent_style); # set $parent_style as style attribute
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: This is good example but my table uses font-size from span which contains this table, is there any way to get font size used in span style? I know it is not correct html syntax but that's how i get html.

Comment: You need to get the `parent` element and use `getAttribute` to retrieve the value of `style`. I've updated my answer.